# Is there a clustering method that allows me to indicate the number of points desired per cluster?

Tags: python, clustering

I've looked into the [various clustering algorithms](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) and realize that specifying an exact cluster size up front sort of defeats the purpose of what clustering is intended to do - identify natural patterns in data. Imposing a size constraint up front might not be something anyone would want to do.

However, I do have a need for a method that allows me to specify the exact number of points allowed per cluster. Is there such an algorithm available or will I unfortunately have to try to write my own?

Comment: The solution I posted at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31879/664 will get you very close: it guarantees the numbers of points in the clusters lie between specified bounds.  Relatively minor modifications to the code in that post would be *one* way of solving your problem.

Comment: @whuber I'll have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CV.SE. Interesting and not too common question (+1), unfortunately you hit a relatively rare clustering sub-task, I haven't seen something authoritative in Python or R, please see my answer for further details.

Comment: @whuber: That is a fun application indeed. I suspect that if you made a gif showing the successive splits, it would be super cool. :)

Comment: @usεr11852 That's a great suggestion.  I am leery of posting animated gifs here on CV, though, because I have found no way to control them: they annoyingly keep cycling.

Answer (score 4):

Being some specific here, the question is not strictly speaking about clustering (i.e. discover underlying data structures) but rather for partitioning with general similarity constraints, to that extent this task is often referred at as [*balanced clustering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_clustering). Finally to help one going forward terminology-wise: we care for "*cluster cardinality*", i.e. the number of elements in the cluster.

An approximate (almost) out-of-the-box solution can be to use $k$-means with some minor modifications; the [ELKI](https://elki-project.github.io/) data mining software has a great tutorial on how to perform [*same-size $k$-means variation*](https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/same-size_k_means), it contains example in Java. Without going into too much detail, we initialise our clustering our $k$-means variant with $k=\frac{n}{p}$ means/centroids, $p$ being the expected cluster cardinality. Then assign up to $p$ elements per cluster and iterate this procedure forward. This is essentially an [*E-M procedure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) same as the one done in "vanilla" $k$-means but with constraints during the $E$ step (Expectation - label assignment). The link present the whole procedure in with great care.

The above being said, the formal treatment of the problem is not trivial, there is a somewhat sparse technical work on the subject. Basically we need to reformulate this problem as an optimisation task with certain discrete constraints. For starters I  would recommend looking at: [*Balanced K-Means for Clustering*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-44415-3_4) (2014) by Malinen and Fränti and [*Balanced Clustering: A Uniform Model and Fast Algorithm*](https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2019/414) (2019) by Lin et al. Unfortunately I have not seen any curated Python implementations on any of these papers; you might want to directly reach out to the authors.

Comment: @user11852 Thank you for the insightful response. "the formal treatment of the problem is not trivial, there is a somewhat sparse technical work on the subject" <-- That certainly appears to be the case. I'll check out the resources you provided and hope a Python implementation emerges!

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

@Eyal Shulman's [python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63886256) provides a K-means method that allows one to define cluster cardinality.

Comment: Nice... (+1) (For the record, that function is the initial step of what ELKI methodology describes, we need to do a few more to ensure some slight stability)